# Weather app using es6 modules

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, modules

i have recently built this simple [weather-app](https://github.com/refatalsakka/weather-app).
I would be happy to get some criticisms to improve my code.

Structure:

[image: Structure]

app.js:

```
import '../sass/style.scss';

import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min';
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';

import elements from './modules/elements';
import update from './modules/document';

(() => {
  function run(cityName) {
    update(cityName);
    setInterval(() => update(cityName), (60000 * 10));
  }
  run('homs');

  elements.form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    run(elements.search.value);
  });
})();
```

modules/apis.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
import axios from 'axios';

const apiWeather = {
  base: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
  key: process.env.API_TOCKEN_WEATHER,
  query: '&units=metric',
};

const apiTime = {
  base: 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/',
  key: process.env.API_TOCKEN_WEATHER,
  query: '&units=metric',
};

export function getWeather(city) {
  return axios
    .get(`${apiWeather.base}weather?q=${city}&appid=${apiWeather.key}${apiWeather.query}`)
    .then((response) => response.data).catch(() => false);
}

export function getTime(uluru) {
  return axios
    .get(`${apiTime.base}onecall?lat=${uluru.lat}&lon=${uluru.lon}&exclude=hourly,minutely,daily,current&appid=${apiTime.key}`)
    .then((response) => response.data).catch(() => false);
}

export function getMap(uluru, mode, id) {
  const mapId = mode === 'dark' ? process.env.API_TOCKEN_MAP_DARK_ID : false;
  const { lat, lon: lng } = uluru;

  const map = new google.maps.Map(id, {
    zoom: 8,
    center: { lat, lng },
    mapId,
  });

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat, lng },
    map,
  });
}
```

modules/document.js

```
import elements from './elements';
import icons from './icons';
import { getWeather, getTime, getMap } from './apis';
import {
  count,
  getMode,
  getIconWeather,
  getIconCountry,
  innerHTML,
  getCurrentDate,
  formatDate,
  information,
} from './helpers';

function addClassNameToBody(className) {
  if (!elements.body.classList.contains(className)) {
    elements.body.classList = '';
    elements.body.classList = className;
  }
}

export default async function update(cityName) {
  elements.error.classList.remove('active');
  elements.loading.classList.add('active');

  const city = await getWeather(cityName);

  if (!city) {
    elements.error.classList.add('active');
    elements.loading.classList.remove('active');
    return;
  }

  const info = information(city);
  const time = await getTime(info.uluru);
  const currentDate = getCurrentDate(time.timezone);
  const mode = getMode(currentDate, { uluru: info.uluru, sunset: info.sunset });
  const weatherIcon = getIconWeather(icons, { status: info.status, mode });
  const countryIcon = getIconCountry(info.country);

  elements.loading.classList.remove('active');

  addClassNameToBody(mode);
  innerHTML(elements.city, (`${info.name},${info.country} ${countryIcon}`));
  innerHTML(elements.date, formatDate(currentDate));
  innerHTML(elements.description, info.description);
  innerHTML(elements.icon, weatherIcon);
  innerHTML(elements.pressure, Math.round(info.pressure));
  innerHTML(elements.humidity, Math.round(info.humidity));
  innerHTML(elements.wind, Math.round(info.wind));
  innerHTML(elements.visibility, Math.round(info.visibility / 1000));
  count(elements.temp_main, Math.round(info.temp));
  count(elements.temp_min, Math.round(info.temp_min));
  count(elements.temp_max, Math.round(info.temp_max));
  count(elements.feels_like, Math.round(info.feels_like));
  getMap(info.uluru, mode, elements.map);
}
```

modules/elements.js

```
export default {
  body: document.querySelector('body'),
  form: document.querySelector('.search form'),
  search: document.querySelector('.search form input'),
  loading: document.querySelector('.loading'),
  error: document.querySelector('.error'),
  city: document.querySelector('.city'),
  date: document.querySelector('.date'),
  temp_main: document.querySelector('.main'),
  temp_min: document.querySelector('.temp-min'),
  temp_max: document.querySelector('.temp-max'),
  feels_like: document.querySelector('.feels-like'),
  pressure: document.querySelector('.pressure'),
  humidity: document.querySelector('.humidity'),
  wind: document.querySelector('.wind'),
  visibility: document.querySelector('.visibility'),
  description: document.querySelector('.description'),
  icon: document.querySelector('.icon'),
  map: document.querySelector('.map'),
};
```

modules/helpers.js

```
export function innerHTML(elm, value) {
  elm.innerHTML = value;
}

export function information(city) {
  return {
    name: city.name,
    country: city.sys.country,
    status: city.weather[0].main,
    description: city.weather[0].description,
    temp: city.main.temp,
    temp_min: city.main.temp_min,
    temp_max: city.main.temp_max,
    feels_like: city.main.feels_like,
    pressure: city.main.pressure,
    humidity: city.main.humidity,
    wind: city.wind.speed,
    visibility: city.visibility,
    uluru: { lat: city.coord.lat, lon: city.coord.lon },
    sunset: city.sys.sunset,
  };
}

export function count(elm, _new) {
  let finish = false;
  let old = Number(elm.innerText);
  const counting = setInterval(() => {
    if (old > _new) {
      old -= 1;
    } else if (old < _new) {
      old += 1;
    } else {
      finish = true;
      clearInterval(counting);
    }
    innerHTML(elm, old);
    if (finish) elm.classList.toggle('active');
  }, 100);
}

export function dateToTimestamp(date) {
  return new Date(date).getTime() / 1000;
}

export function formatDate(data) {
  return new Date(data).toLocaleString('en-US', {
    day: '2-digit',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    weekday: 'long',
    hour12: false,
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
  });
}

export function getCurrentDate(timeZone) {
  return new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone });
}

export function getMode(currentDate, city) {
  return city.sunset >= dateToTimestamp(currentDate) ? 'light' : 'dark';
}

export function getIconWeather(icons, city) {
  const { status, mode } = city;
  const index = icons.natural[status.toLowerCase()] ? 'natural' : mode;
  return icons[index][status.toLowerCase()];
}

export function getIconCountry(code) {
  return `<img src="https://openweathermap.org/images/flags/${code.toLowerCase()}.png" title="${code.toLowerCase()}"/>`;
}
```

modules/icons.js

```
export default {
  light: {
    clear: '<i class="fas fa-sun"></i>',
    clouds: '<i class="fas fa-cloud-sun"></i>',
    rain: '<i class="fas fa-cloud-sun-rain"></i>',
  },
  dark: {
    clear: '<i class="fas fa-moon"></i>',
    clouds: '<i class="fas fa-cloud-moon"></i>',
    rain: '<i class="fas fa-cloud-moon-rain"></i>',
  },
  natural: {
    snow: '<i class="fas fa-snowflake"></i>',
    fog: '<i class="fas fa-smog"></i>',
    mist: '<i class="fas fa-smog"></i>',
    smog: '<i class="fas fa-smog"></i>',
    drizzle: '<i class="fas fa-cloud-rain"></i>',
    storm: '<i class="fas fa-poo-storm"></i>',
    bolt: '<i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>',
    wind: '<i class="fas fa-wind"></i>',
    rainbow: '<i class="fas fa-rainbow"></i>',
  },
};
```